# program that Replaces lines of a file with its reverse

Tags: arraylist, io, reverse, filenotfoundexception, printwriter

Am writing an algorithm that takes an IO input file with a text, read it process it and then output a file with its reverse text.
example:

> Hello word

would be

> drow olleH.

The program compiles but the folder "text_Output" is empty.????

some insight ??

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;


public class Reverse
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  { 

    //read file from user 
    Scanner Input = new Scanner (new File("text_input.txt")) ;
    //  declar arraylist
    ArrayList <String> Lines = new ArrayList <String>();

    //use while loop to copy by line all data from text to array list
    while (Input.hasNextLine())
    {
      //add line to array list
      Lines.add(Input.nextLine());
    }
    Input.close();

    // create new output file
    PrintWriter Output = new PrintWriter(new File("text_Output"));

    //copy data from lines arraylists to new text file
    for (int i =0; i < Lines.size();i++)
    {
      //copy first element into char array
      char[]strLine = Lines.get(i).toString().toCharArray();

      //copy each char to string array in new text file
      for(int j=strLine.length-1;j>=0;j--)
      {   
        //copy index char in file
        Output.print(strLine[j]);
        Output.println();
      } 
      //close the files
      Input.close();
      Output.close ();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop of write, it is reading only first line and then the input and output are closed.I tried with multiple lines of input data and is working fine with below mentioned code.

```
     for (int i =0; i < Lines.size();i++)
        {
          //copy first element into char array
          char[]strLine = Lines.get(i).toString().toCharArray();

          //copy each char to string array in new text file
          for(int j=strLine.length-1;j>=0;j--)
          {   
            //copy index char in file
            Output.print(strLine[j]);

          } 
          Output.println();
        }
// here close the input and output.
}
}
```

Comment: ohh i forget to put .txt a the end but the file is outputting  only one word [yaM] while i have a big text